# ESP32 1:10 bluetooth connection(scatternet)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to configure a bluetooth scatternet with esp32-wrover v3 or esp32-wrover-E. At this time, if one device acting as a bridge in scatternet exists at the same time as the GATT server and the client, wouldn't the problem occur?
The problem I want to know is:

Q1. Is it possible that the connection between the client (Master) and the bridge (Client+server) and the server (slave) are connected at the same time? (means when one device acts as a bridge)

Q2. 1:10 Bluetooth low energy tried to connect 1 master and 10 slaves, but failed.
I understand that this is a situation where the physical connection of the ESP32 is only up to 7. Is this the cause?

Q3. I want to configure 3 scatternets to connect 1:10 at the same time with ESP32.
What I am trying to configure is one master and two bridges, and four of each bridge are connected to slave(server).
At this time, if this connection method is connected at the same time, does not a problem occur?

Q4. The example source I used in the esp-idf framework is as follows.

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gattc_multi_connect

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gatt_server

In the original source, 1 application and 1 profile are combined and connected to 1 device. Using this source, I tried to manage multiple devices with one application and one profile through conditional statements that classify multiple devices in the callback function using only one application. However, at this time, there is no problem when connecting one, but when trying to connect a second device, the device connected in front of it is disconnected. Do you know what is causing this?
Or, if you know about the process of esp GATT Client event occurring, please answer.

(Additional question. Can I know the operation process and management of tasks managed through FreeRTOS in esp32 bluetooth?)

Thank you.

Comment: Would BLE Mesh be better for your application? https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/esp-ble-mesh/ble-mesh-index.html

Comment: I'll check regarding BLE MESH.Thank you.

Comment: I have one more question.
If esp32-wrover-E is used and the existing ESP-IDF is not used, is 1:10 BLE communication possible when MESH is configured in Bluetooth 4.0?